# Enhanced android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I am creating an app which can play my radio stream. I am using MediaPlayer, but it is not enough. For example, buffering time is unpredictable, buffering time is not available. I would like to use an other mediaplayer, which is fast, and e.g. I can set the buffering time. Is there any open source solution?

Comment: Maybe you can do the buffering yourself and pass the parts to mediaplayer

Comment: But mediaplayer only accepts uri...

Comment: You could try the Android Exoplayer and see if that helps. It is an open source project that has more capabilities than the built in media player.